# Change AppTheme dynamically

Tags: android, xml, themes

**Goal**: I want to allow user to change the color theme of my app.

**Themes** (styles.xml):

```xml
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/indigoColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/indigoColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/indigoColorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/indigoColorPrimaryDark</item>

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.FullScreen">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.MainActivity">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.SearchActivity">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Colors -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Indigo">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/indigoColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/indigoColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/indigoColorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/indigoColorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Blue">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blueColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blueColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blueColorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/blueColorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Red">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/redColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/redColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/redColorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/redColorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <!-- some other colors -->

</resources>
```

As you can see, I have the main theme `AppTheme` that as a default color ("indigo").
I have three other themes `FullScreen`, `MainActivity` and `SearchActivity` that derive from `AppTheme`, and then colors themes.

**AndroidManifest**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.superbstudios.reportnote">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".SignInActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullScreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SearchActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".GuideActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_guide"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now, only `SignInActiviy`, `MainActivity` and `SearchActivity` has their own themes, the other activity (also application) has `AppTheme`.

**What I do**: I create a `BaseActivity` class, and all activity extend this class.
In `BaseActivity` in `onCreate` method before `super` declaration I use this code to change color theme:

```
setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Red);
```

**Problem**: This code change the theme for all activity and also for `SignInActiviy`, `MainActivity` and `SearchActivity` that needs a different theme.

*I don't know if the colors theme are useful.*
*The only things i want is to change the `AppTheme` colors like this:*

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/redColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/redColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/redColorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/redColorPrimaryDark</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**So, what I have to do to change colors of my app?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing styles.xml

```xml
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/indigoColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/indigoColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/indigoColorAccent</item>

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.FullScreen">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.MainActivity">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.SearchActivity">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Colors -->
    <style name="Indigo">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/indigoColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/indigoColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/indigoColorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Blue">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blueColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blueColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blueColorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Red">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/redColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/redColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/redColorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And in my BaseActivity i use this code:

```
getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.Blue, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Referenced to the comment**

I'll answer by taking Red color as an example

If you only want to change the colorPrimary then keep only it.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Red"> 
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/redColorPrimary</item> 
</style>
```

Other wise create two themes for Red color. One with status bar color and other inheriting that with transparent status bar.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Red"> 
     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/redColorPrimary</item>
     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/redColorPrimaryDark</item>
     <item name="colorAccent">@color/redColorAccent</item> 
     <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/redColorPrimaryDark</item> 
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.RedTransparentStatus" parent="AppTheme.Red> 
     <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item> 
</style>
```

So if you want status bar to transparent you can set the second theme or else the first.

---

From my understanding, you want to keep the default "Indigo" color for 
**SignInActivity**, **MainActivity**, **SearchActivity**.

Todo so inherit the relevant themes of those activities with AppTheme

```
<style name="AppTheme.SearchActivity" parent="AppTheme">
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: No, i explain it bad. For example **MainActivity** has `AppTheme.MainActivity` that has only status bar color 'transparent', but if I set AppTheme.Red, the status bar will be red...how can I leave it transparent?

Comment: To make it simpler, I only need to change AppTheme `colorPrimary` to `@color/redColorPrimary`, ecc. I don't know if colors Theme are useful....

Comment: @Broge There is a solution but may not be ideal. I'll update the answer